# Checking for keyboard inputs uses too much cpu usage, Is there something wrong with my code?

Tags: python

Im making a simple music  player so i can pause music when i am in full screen applications. The code works fine but i noticed that it uses around 15% cpu usage. Im just wondering if i did something wrong with my code.

```
import keyboard

listedSongs = []
currentSong = "idk"
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('alt+k'):
        i = 1
        paused = False
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('alt+q'):
        break
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('alt+s'):
        if currentSong not in listedSongs:
                listedSongs.append(currentSong)
                print(listedSongs)
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest reason it's consuming so many resources is this:

```
while True:
```

In essence, the program *never stops to wait for anything*. It's checking *constantly*, over and over, to see if the buttons on the keyboard are pressed. A better way, that's much less costly on the computer, is to assign a "callback" to be called whenever your desired key is pressed, and have the program sleep in between key presses. The `keyboard` library provides this functionality:

```
import keyboard
import time

listedSongs = []
currentSong = "idk"
exit = False  # make a loop control variable

def alt_k():
    i = 1
    paused = False

def alt_q(): 
    exit = True

def alt_s():
    if currentSong not in listedSongs:
        listedSongs.append(currentSong)
        print(listedSongs)

# assign hooks to the keyboard
keyboard.on_press_key("alt+k", alt_k)  # on press alt+k, execute alt_k()
keyboard.on_press_key("alt+q", alt_q)
keyboard.on_press_key("alt+s", alt_s)

# main loop
while not exit:
    keyboard.wait()  # "block" for input (essentially, do nothing until a key is pressed and yield CPU resources to anything else that wants them)
```