# Checking for keyboard inputs not Working. Help Please

Tags: python, keyboard

I am trying this code provided and accepted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55369170/14307622
but I am getting this error. Any ideas why ? I am new here so if I am breaking some rules for this question, then please let me know but if possible, please suggest some solutions to the problem first.

```
import keyboard
import time

listedSongs = []
currentSong = "idk"
exit = False  # make a loop control variable

def alt_k():
    i = 1
    paused = False

def alt_q(): 
    global exit
    exit = True

def alt_s():
    if currentSong not in listedSongs:
        listedSongs.append(currentSong)
        print(listedSongs)

# assign hooks to the keyboard
keyboard.on_press_key("alt+k", alt_k)  # on press alt+k, execute alt_k()
keyboard.on_press_key("alt+q", alt_q)
keyboard.on_press_key("alt+s", alt_s)

# main loop
while not exit:
    keyboard.wait()  # "block" for input (essentially, do nothing until a key is pressed and yield CPU resources to anything else that wants them)
```

The error I am getting is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\AJ\Coding\test.py", line 26, in <module>
    keyboard.on_press_key("alt+k", alt_k)  # on press alt+k, execute alt_k()
  File "C:\Users\AJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 510, in on_press_key
    return hook_key(key, lambda e: e.event_type == KEY_UP or callback(e), suppress=suppress)
  File "C:\Users\AJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 493, in hook_key
    scan_codes = key_to_scan_codes(key)
  File "C:\Users\AJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 324, in key_to_scan_codes
    raise ValueError('Key {} is not mapped to any known key.'.format(repr(key)), e)
ValueError: ("Key 'alt+k' is not mapped to any known key.", ValueError("Key name 'alt+k' is not mapped to any known key."))
```

Comment: We need the entire traceback to be able to diagnose the error. Of the obvious, you're assigning to global variables without declaring them in the functions (i.e. the `alt_q` function needs a line saying `global exit` at the top).

Comment: aalways put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: @thebjorn

I have updated the error I am getting as you suggested and also updated the 'global exit' in alt_q function, I am still getting the same error. Any more suggestions ?

Comment: @furas

Thanks for guiding me. I have done what you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `on_press_key()` works only with single key like `q` but not with combination `alt+q`. Or maybe it is problem only on some systems. At least it doesn't work on my Linux.

Or maybe they change code in module. Answer in [Checking for keyboard inputs uses too much cpu usage, Is there something wrong with my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55369170/1832058) is 2 years old.

---

You can use `add_hotkey()` and it doesn't need `wait()`

```
import keyboard
import time

listedSongs = []
currentSong = "idk"

exit = False  # make a loop control variable

def alt_k():
    print('pressed: alt+k')
    
    i = 1
    paused = False

def alt_q(): 
    global exit  # need it to assign `True` to global/external variable instead of creating local variable

    print('pressed: alt+q')
    
    exit = True

def alt_s():
    print('pressed: alt+s')

    if currentSong not in listedSongs:
        listedSongs.append(currentSong)
        print(listedSongs)

keyboard.add_hotkey('alt+k', alt_k)
keyboard.add_hotkey('alt+q', alt_q)
keyboard.add_hotkey('alt+s', alt_s)

# main loop
while not exit:
    time.sleep(1)
```

See examples in documentation: [Example](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#example)

---

Eventually you may use `hotkye = read_hotkey(...)` with `if/else` to execute correct function.

I'm not sure but sometimes it works for me also with `hotkey = keyboard.wait(suppress=False)` but sometimes it doesn't work.

```
while not exit:
    hotkey = keyboard.read_hotkey(suppress=False)
    #hotkey = keyboard.wait(suppress=False)

    print('hotkey:', hotkey)

    if hotkey == 'alt+k':
        alt_k()
    elif hotkey == 'alt+q':
        alt_q()
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer but I have a big issue. I am trying to create a script in which I am using the hotkey 'windows+L' (which btw I know is to lock windows), I am trying to put a function in my script to shut down my display when I press 'windows + L'. The code you provided successfully made it happen but ONLY ONCE. Once, the said hotkey is pressed, the script hangs and no other hotkey is working after that which were working before just fine. It is driving me mad. Any ideas why this may be happening ? I have to close the script using 'Ctrl+C' to exit script once it hangs.

Comment: New information has just come to light. The windows key has nothing to do with the script hanging. Once you lock windows, all your hotkeys stop working which missed the whole point of hotkeys for convenience. So, you can set all the hotkeys, once you lock your system, everything seems lost. No idea how to get this to work... Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: do you have problem when it is locked or after you unlock it? Do you want to use `hotkeys` when window is locked? But lock has to block access to computer for security reason - someone could still your data. Eventually you could check [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) instead of `Python` - maybe it can work when system is locked. I don't use Windows so I can't test it.

Comment: No, I don't want to use my PC when it is locked. (Sorry if you came to that conclusion after my comment. In simple terms, the code you wrote above works great, all the keypresses are detected as they should but ONCE you LOCK and then UNLOCK your windows account, the key presses are not detected (your script was running when I locked my account). I posted a question regarding this, if you want to have a look, then here is the link to that question, it is explained better there (hopefully.). Here is the link to the question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/67505554/14307622

Comment: I don't use WIndows so I can't help. The only idea to use other tool - maybe [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) will work better. It was create specially for Windows. Or you may try other module [pynput.keyboard.Listener](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html)

Comment: It is okay, maybe someone else will. I am new and I know AutoHotKey is a solution I can try and the whole of Internet seems rather enthralled by the program and don't get me wrong, I like it too but I am learning Python these days and I hate it when I have to jump to some other program to do something which should be easy enough to do anywhere. 

The idea was to create an app which can contain all my custom hotkeys, the app can run in the background and that's it. It should not be too hard to do in any language and especially in Python which is so much fun to write. Not giving up just yet.

Comment: On Linux I use [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey) for hotkeys and it works after unlocking on Linux - and it is created in Python. If it would work on Windows then you could check its source code. Other idea to try to use `PyQt` for global hotkeys. ie [pyqtkeybind](https://github.com/codito/pyqtkeybind)

Comment: I have downloaded AutoKey but I refuge to give up. I want to do it in python and I will use your suggestions and let you know how it goes.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved my issue.

I ditched the keyboard module since it was not working the way I wanted it to and then I used the [Python Global-Hotkeys Module](https://pypi.org/project/global-hotkeys/). The code was pretty much the same but now everything just clicked in place.

Hope this helps someone in the future.