# Python Keyboard Module add_hotkey is not working after you lock windows Once. Help Needed

Tags: python, module, keyboard, global-hotkey

This is the code that is working until I press windows+L to lock my windows PC. Once I lock my PC and then unlock it, the hotkeys stop working and the terminal window is hung. I have to exit the program by keyboard interrupt. Here is the working or not-working code.

```
import sys
from keyboard import add_hotkey

def keyDetector():

    add_hotkey('ctrl+F2', ctrl_f2)   
    add_hotkey('ctrl+F3', ctrl_f3)   
    add_hotkey('ctrl+F4', ctrl_f4)
    add_hotkey('ctrl+F12', ctrl_f12) 
    add_hotkey('windows+l', win_l)

    while not exit:
        sleep(1)

def ctrl_f2():
    print(" You pressed control + F2.")


def ctrl_f3():
    print(" You pressed control + F3.")


def ctrl_f4():
    print(" You pressed control + F4.")


def ctrl_f12():
    global exit
    print(" You have pressed control + F12, exiting the program now.")
    exit = True
    sys.exit()


def win_l():
    print(" You pressed Windows + L.")
```

I would like to point out once again that when I run the code, everything works fine until I lock my windows and then unlock it, that is when everything goes awry.

Comment: I don't use Windows to test it but maybe module [pynput.keyboard.Listener](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html) will better work. Or you should try to use [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) instead of Python. It was create specially for Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved my issue.

I ditched the keyboard module since it was not working the way I wanted it to and then I used the [Python Global-Hotkeys Module](https://pypi.org/project/global-hotkeys/). The code was pretty much the same but now everything just clicked in place.

Hope this helps someone in the future. Here is the modified code.

```
import sys
from global_hotkeys import *

is_alive = True


def ctrl_f2():
    print(" You pressed control + F2.")


def ctrl_f3():
    print(" You pressed control + F3.")


def ctrl_f6():
    print(" You pressed control + F4.")


def ctrl_f12():
    global is_alive
    print(" You have pressed control + F12, exiting the program now.")
    is_alive = False
    sys.exit()



bindings = [
    [["control", "f2"], None, ctrl_f2],
    [["control", "f3"], None, ctrl_f31],
    [["control", "f6"], None, ctrl_f6],
    [["control", "f12"], None, ctrl_f12],
]

while is_alive:
    sleep(0.1)
```